# How to give property to agents Netlogo

Tags: netlogo, patch

I´m setting up some turtles randomly on the the map, then they have to change the color of the patches to show that they cultivated however some times they overlap and change the color of other turtles. To solve this i asked  `not any? other turtles in-radius 6` to force them to be apart, but this is not elegant nor efficient. What would be a better way to give each turtle their own patch to make a more populated world.

```
to setup 
  ca
  resize-world 0 100 0 100
create-turtles 50

  [ set size 1
    set color 135
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    move-to one-of patches with [not any? other turtles in-radius 6]
    ask patches in-radius (2 + random 2) [set pcolor 35] 
  ]
end

to go 
  
ask turtles[ ask patches in-radius 4  with [pcolor = 35]; falta representar las cosechas 4-2-3-3
    [ set pcolor 42]]
  
end
```

The go is using the fact that there are no turtles in a radius of 6, but if i wanted to get them closer or change the color on different ticks this would be bad.

Thanks. If more is need please let me know.

Comment: Do you want each patch to have a unique owner or can multiple turtles cultivate the same patch?

Comment: I think you should share an example of the code which causes the first unwanted behaviour that you encountered, i.e. turtles changing other turtles' colors instead of only changing patches' colors. This shouldn't happen in the first place, so it might be worth to address this point first, instead of its workaround

Comment: @Matteo I think he meant turtles changing the color of patches that belong to another turtle.

Comment: Matteo and Leirs Thanks for answering. Yes the problem i encountered was that if i didnt use the not any turtles some turtles would overlap the crops and so it would seem that a turtle was cultivating land that wasnt his.

Answer (score 2):

You can give the turtles a new turtles-variable that you can assign a `patch-set` to. This is done by using `turtles-own` at the start of your program.
The turtle then remembers which patches were assigned to this variable and can access them again at a later time. This way, when it comes time to change patch colors, they only change the colors of patches within their original radius and not of the patches in the extended radius.

```
turtles-own [territory]

to setup 
  ca
  resize-world 0 100 0 100
create-turtles 50

  [ set size 1
    set color 135
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set territory patches in-radius (2 + random 2)
    ask territory [set pcolor 35] 
  ]
  
  
  
end

to go 
  
  ask turtles [ ask territory ; falta representar las cosechas 4-2-3-3
    [ set pcolor 42]]
  
end
```

As an alternative solution, here it is not the turtles that remember which patch they own, but the patches that remember which turtle owns them. In the case I use here, patches can only be owned by a single turtle.
Here, I give each patch a patch-variable using `patches-own`. I then let the turtles tell the patches within their radius to choose that turtle as their owner `ask patches ... [set owner myself]`. `Myself` is a reporter that refers not to the patch carrying out the command, but to the turtle that asked the patch to carry out the command.

```
patches-own [owner]

to setup 
  ca
  resize-world 0 100 0 100
  
  create-turtles 50 [
    set size 1
    set color 135
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    ask patches in-radius (2 + random 2) [
      set owner myself
      set pcolor 35
    ]
  ]

end

to go 
  
  ask turtles [ ask patches in-radius 4 with [owner = myself] ; falta representar las cosechas 4-2-3-3
    [ set pcolor 42]
  ]
  
end
```

If multiple turtles try to be the owner of the same patch, the last one becomes the owner. This is because each turtle completely overwrites the previous owner value.

If you still want an option for multiple owners, you can work with a `turtle-set` instead. This requires a few different primitives.
In setup, you have to define owners as an empty turtle-set in order for the rest to work, using `set owners (turtle-set)`.
To then assign a turtle to owners, you use `set owners (turtle-set owners myself)`. This changes the owners turtle-set to add the turtle calling the patch to the set.
Finally, you can no longer ask patches to `with [owner = myself]` to change color since `owners` is now a turtle-set, not a turtle. Instead, you use the `member?` primitive that looks if a turtle is part of a turtle-set.

```
patches-own [owners]

to setup 
  ca
  resize-world 0 100 0 100
  ask patches [set owners (turtle-set)]
  
  create-turtles 50 [
    set size 1
    set color 135
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    ask patches in-radius (2 + random 2) [
      set owners (turtle-set owners myself)
      set pcolor 35
    ]
  ]

end

to go 
  
  ask turtles [ 
    ask patches in-radius 4 with [member? myself owners] ; falta representar las cosechas 4-2-3-3
    [ set pcolor 42]
  ]
  
end
```

Comment: I like this solution! Im going to try it before giving the check mark to see if it works as intended. Thanks

Comment: In this example, multiple turtles can still own the same crop. If you want it the other way around where a crop can only be operated by a single turtle, I suggest working with a patch-variable instead

Comment: +1, however note that using `patch-set` is superflous: `patches in-radius (2 + random 2)` is already a patch-set as such. Also, perhaps I would integrate in your answer the point you made in your comment, as to me it seems central to the question

Comment: @Matteo Oh right, I will edit the `patch-set`. I was not sure if the question was pertaining to turtles discoloring patches outside of their original range, or if the OP wanted to have each patch be property of only a single turtle. The second one requires more decisions though, with rules deciding which turtle gets ownership of a patch that is close to two or more turtles. As the OP didn't mention anything about such decisions, I left it out for now.

Comment: Uhh thats very intriguing, have turtles "fight" for the ownership of land. I haven't come around to it but it sounds pretty interesting. But the idea is that at setup each turtle has its own set of land  so the radius given at the beginning can only be changed by the turtle that had it at the beginning. How would it be done with a patch-own variable?

Comment: @bksnlow I have added two options for patch-variables. I hope it can help you.